# Integrate a function over the union sphere (Stokes)?!

Tags: integration, riemann-sphere

I have problems solving this integral since 2 days -.-

$\int_{S^2} f \cdot n \; dS \; \; \;$ with

$f(x,y,z):=(y^3, z^3, x^3)^T$, $\; \; S^2=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} | x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1\}$ and $n$ ist the outer normal vector.

We -theoretically- "learned" the theorem of Stokes and may use it.

Thanks for any help :-)

Edit1: Stokes was: $\int_{\partial S} f = \int_{S}$d$f$? The professor never uses "$n\cdot f$" but the guy publishing the tasks does... confusing like hell. Thanks for unraveling this one!
What does your $\land$ mean?

Comment: Well then, you have $\int_{\partial B_1(0,0,0)}y^3dy\wedge dz + z^3 dx\wedge dz + x^3 dx\wedge dy$. What does Stokes's theorem say?

Comment: what do you mean for $f\cdot n\ dS$?

Comment: @janmarqz it's another notation for $\int f\cdot dS$, or put differently, another notation for the integral I listed above.

Comment: more notations $\Rightarrow$ more confusion

Comment: @janmarqz a saying of W. Churchill comes to mind; notation for integration along manifolds does tend to be confusing, but the alternative...

Comment: was he mathematician?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want Stokes' Theorem. You want the Divergence Theorem, which is usually stated in Calculus classes for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ vector functions $\vec{f}$ as follows: Let $S$ be a smooth closed surface enclosing a volume $V$. Let $\vec{f}$ be a continuously differentiable vector function on an open set containing $S$ and $V$ (this is simplest to state.) Then
$$
                 \int_{S} \vec{f}\cdot d\vec{S} = \int_{V}\nabla\cdot \vec{f}\,dV.
$$
On the left, $\int_{S}\vec{f}\cdot d\vec{S}$ means $\int_{S}\vec{f}\cdot \hat{n}\,dS$; $\vec{n}$ is the unit outward normal to $S$; and $dS$ means the area measure on $S$. On the right side, $dV$ means the usual volume measure in $V$, and $\nabla\cdot$ is the divergence operator.

Comment: $\nabla f = 0$ in this case, right? Plus I can set $V = B_{1}(0,0,0)$? So I'd have $\int_{S^2} f \cdot n dS= 1$

Comment: @swiknaba: $\nabla\cdot \vec{f}=0$. So $\int \vec{f}\cdot \hat{n}dS=0$.

Comment: okay, thanks! :)